# How to fix try-runtime execution aborted issue?

Tags: try-runtime, storage-migration

Trying to do a try-runtime in a test node using the command -

`try-runtime --runtime ./target/release/wbuild/alphanet-runtime/alphanet_runtime.wasm on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://IP:PORT`

and getting the below error.

```
     panicked at 'Bad input data provided to on_runtime_upgrade: Codec error', /Users/immanueljohn/runtime/alphanet/src/lib.rs:201:1
thread 'main' panicked at cli/main.rs:334:6:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Input("failed to execute TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed\nWASM backtrace:\nerror while executing at wasm backtrace:\n    0: 0x3a744e - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind\n    1: 0x36eba8 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::he56f452e7c6bafaf\n    2: 0x2ca56c - <unknown>!TryRuntime_on_runtime_upgrade")
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/cc66ad468955717ab92600c770da8c1601a4ff33/library/std/src/panicking.rs:595:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/cc66ad468955717ab92600c770da8c1601a4ff33/library/core/src/panicking.rs:67:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/cc66ad468955717ab92600c770da8c1601a4ff33/library/core/src/result.rs:1652:5
   3: tokio::runtime::park::CachedParkThread::block_on
   4: try_runtime::main
```

Comment: Can uou share your runtime code? Specifically what is around line 201 in your lib.rs file?

Comment: https://github.com/capsule-corp-ternoa/ternoa-node/blob/36fc7f8dbaad6d8efc1ee076ceb601efe3c7773d/runtime/alphanet/src/lib.rs#L201

Comment: @ImmanuelJohn did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Would appreciate if this one is answered, I'm getting the same error